# Removing the Stripe Checkout Button in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have successfully implemented the checkout Button in React Js. [image]

I will like to change this button to a picture [image]

Please I will like to ask whether there is any hack around this because this Stripe checkout Button is not easy to remove.

My checkout Form Looks like

```
render() {
    const {amount, description} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>

            <StripeCheckout
              // name={name}
               description={description}
               amount={amount*100}
               token={this.onToken}
               stripeKey={STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE}
               name={'stripe-test'}
               image={apiConstants.API_IMAGES+'logos/logo.jpg'}
               label={"Cash In $"+amount +' using Cards' }
            />
            <div className="music-text-center">
                     <span className="ml-1 site-second-color">   
                         <Trans><h6> <b>{this.state.message}</b></h6></Trans>
                     </span>
             </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nges Brian, what you want to do to customize Stripe Checkout is to use the custom integration 
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom 

where the button is controlled by you and you could style it as you want to including make it an image button.

Answer (score 0):

you can add styling to button like so:

```
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";

class Payments extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StripeCheckout
          name="survey"
          description="survey credits"
          amount={500}
          token={token => this.props.handleToken(token)}
          stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}
        >
          <button className="btn">Add Credits</button>
        </StripeCheckout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```